# How to make composite id from two foreign keys in hibernate.xml file

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have one table **Order**. It has two foreign keys **applicationId** and **customerId**.
I have made these two as foreign keys but the thing is that how should I make a **composite primary key** using these two for my Order table ?

This is how I declared foreign keys in Order.hibernate.xml file :

```
<one-to-one name="application" class="Application" column="applicationId" cascade="all" />  
<many-to-one name="customer" class="Customer" column="customerId" cascade="all" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `<composite-id>` mapping and the columns of the `one-to-one` and `many-to-one` mappings have to be made `insertable = false, updatable = false`, or you remodel them as `key-many-to-one` mappings inside of the `composite-id` mapping.